# specify oauth2 access token with appengine remote_api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-app-engine-python

I try to use appengine [remote_api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api).

It works, but I need to launch the shell by specifying directly the oauth2 access token. I can't store it on continuous integration environment (Travis).

I'd like to do the same think as we can do with appcfg.py:

appcfg.py oauth2_access_token=foo --oauth2_refresh_token=bar

Is there a way to do that ? Or did you found a workaround ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? Thanks.